# INotifyPropertyChanged does not work in Resettable view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I tried to use a resettable view model originally posted by Nish Nishant in https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=158591
But somehow the INotifyPropertyChanged does not work for LabelContent and OkCancelButtonVis property when I execute the DeleteBahanExecute method. Does anybody know why? Here is the MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="XLMPIS.MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XLMPIS"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:XLMPIS.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="800">
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Inventory">
            <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:ViewModels.BahanViewModel}}">
                <Grid Margin="0 10 0 0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding TipeBahans}" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="left" SelectedItem="{Binding SelTipeBahan, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="NamaTipeBahanGsm" Padding="2"/>
                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Suppliers}" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="left" SelectedItem="{Binding SelSupplier, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="NamaSupplier" Padding="2"/>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Margin="0 10 0 0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Huruf Kode Bahan" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="2"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding HurufKodeBahan, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Background="{Binding TBBackground}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="{Binding IsReadOnly}" PreviewTextInput="LetterValidationTextBox" Padding="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="No. Awal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="2"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding NoAwal, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="3" Background="{Binding TBBackground}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="{Binding IsReadOnly}" PreviewTextInput="IntegerValidationTextBox" Padding="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="No. Akhir" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="2"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding NoAkhir, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="5" Background="{Binding TBBackground}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="{Binding IsReadOnly}" PreviewTextInput="IntegerValidationTextBox" Padding="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" Text="Lebar" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="2"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding NewLebar, Mode=TwoWay}" PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" Grid.Column="7" Background="{Binding TBBackground}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Padding="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="8" Text="Panjang" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="2"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding NewPanjang, Mode=TwoWay}" PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" Grid.Column="9" Background="{Binding TBBackground}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Padding="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="10" Text="Sisa" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="2"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding NewSisa, Mode=TwoWay}" PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" Grid.Column="11" Background="{Binding TBBackground}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Padding="2"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Margin="0 10 0 0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Surat Jalan" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="2"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding NewSuratJalan, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Background="{Binding TBBackground}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Padding="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Tanggal Masuk" Padding="2"/>
                    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding NewTanggalMasuk}" Grid.Column="3" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Margin="0 10 0 0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Add New Bahan" Width="100" Command="{Binding AddNewBahanCommand}" Padding="2"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="10 0 0 0" Content="Delete Bahan" Width="90" Command="{Binding DeleteBahanCommand}" Padding="2"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="2" Margin="10 0 0 0" Content="Refresh" Width="90" Command="{Binding ResetCommand}" Padding="2"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="3" Margin="20 0 0 0" Content="Ok" Visibility="{Binding OkCancelButtonVis,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60" Command="{Binding OkCommand}" Padding="2"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="4" Margin="10 0 0 0" Content="Cancel" Visibility="{Binding OkCancelButtonVis,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="60" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" Padding="2"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Margin="0 10 0 0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Nama Tipe Bahan" Padding="2"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding NewNamaTipeBahan, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Background="{Binding TBBackground}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Padding="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Gsm" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="2"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding NewGsm, Mode=TwoWay}" PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" Grid.Column="3" Background="{Binding TBBackground}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Padding="2"/>
                </Grid>
                <Button Margin="0 10 0 0" Content="Add New Tipe Bahan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120" Command="{Binding AddNewTipeBahanCommand}" Padding="2"/>
                <Label Margin="0 10 0 0" Content="{Binding LabelContent, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
```

This is the View Model Code. I eliminated some of the "using" rows.

```
using XLMPIS.Model;
using XLMPIS.Command;

namespace XLMPIS.ViewModel
{
    public class BahanViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public BahanViewModel()
        {
            SelTipeBahan = new TipeBahan();
            TipeBahans = new ObservableCollection<TipeBahan>();
            Suppliers = new ObservableCollection<Supplier>();
            SelSupplier = new Supplier();
            SqlDbConnect sdc = new SqlDbConnect();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sdc.SqlQuery("select * from TTipeBahan");
            ds = sdc.QueryEx("TTipeBahan");
            dt = ds.Tables["TTipeBahan"];
            int tmpIndex = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                TipeBahans.Add(new TipeBahan());
                TipeBahans[tmpIndex].TipeBahanID = (int)dr["TipeBahanID"];
                TipeBahans[tmpIndex].NamaTipeBahan = dr["NamaTipeBahan"].ToString();
                TipeBahans[tmpIndex].Gsm = (int)dr["Gsm"];
                tmpIndex++;
            }
            SelTipeBahan = TipeBahans[SELECTED_INDEX];

            sdc.SqlQuery("select NamaSupplier,SupplierID from TSupplier");
            ds = sdc.QueryEx("TSupplier");
            dt = ds.Tables["TSupplier"];
            tmpIndex = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Suppliers.Add(new Supplier());
                Suppliers[tmpIndex].SupplierID = (int)dr["SupplierID"];
                Suppliers[tmpIndex].NamaSupplier= dr["NamaSupplier"].ToString();
                tmpIndex++;
            }
            SelSupplier = Suppliers[SELECTED_INDEX];

            sdc.SqlDbClose();

            NewTanggalMasuk = DateTime.Today;
            IsReadOnly = false;//not read only
            TBBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White); //white textbox
            OkCancelButtonVis = "Hidden";
            LabelContent = "test";
        }

        private const int SELECTED_INDEX = 0;

        private ObservableCollection<Supplier> _suppliers;

        public ObservableCollection<Supplier> Suppliers
        {
            get { return _suppliers; }
            set { _suppliers = value; }
        }

        private string _noawal;

        public string NoAwal
        {
            get { return _noawal; }
            set { _noawal = value; }
        }

        private string _noakhir;

        public string NoAkhir
        {
            get { return _noakhir; }
            set { _noakhir = value; }
        }

        private string _okcancelbuttonvis;

        public string OkCancelButtonVis
        {
            get { return _okcancelbuttonvis; }
            set { _okcancelbuttonvis = value; FirePropertyChanged("OkCancelButtonVis"); }
        }

        private string _labelcontent;

        public string LabelContent
        {
            get { return _labelcontent; }
            set { _labelcontent = value; FirePropertyChanged("LabelContent"); }
        }

        private string _hurufkodebahan;

        public string HurufKodeBahan
        {
            get { return _hurufkodebahan; }
            set { _hurufkodebahan = value; }
        }

        private string _newsuratjalan;

        public string NewSuratJalan
        {
            get { return _newsuratjalan; }
            set { _newsuratjalan = value; }
        }

        private string _newgsm;

        public string NewGsm
        {
            get { return _newgsm; }
            set { _newgsm = value; }
        }

        private string _newnamatipebahan;

        public string NewNamaTipeBahan
        {
            get { return _newnamatipebahan; }
            set { _newnamatipebahan = value; }
        }

        private string _newlebar;

        public string NewLebar
        {
            get { return _newlebar; }
            set { _newlebar = value; }
        }

        private string _newpanjang;

        public string NewPanjang
        {
            get { return _newpanjang; }
            set { _newpanjang = value; }
        }

        private string _newsisa;

        public string NewSisa
        {
            get { return _newsisa; }
            set { _newsisa = value; }
        }

        private DateTime _newtanggalmasuk;

        public DateTime NewTanggalMasuk
        {
            get { return _newtanggalmasuk; }
            set { _newtanggalmasuk = value; }
        }

        private Supplier _selsupplier;

        public Supplier SelSupplier
        {
            get { return _selsupplier; }
            set { _selsupplier = value; }
        }

        private TipeBahan _seltipebahan;

        public TipeBahan SelTipeBahan
        {
            get { return _seltipebahan; }
            set
            {
                _seltipebahan = value;
                FirePropertyChanged("SelTipeBahan");


        }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<TipeBahan> _tipebahans;

        public ObservableCollection<TipeBahan> TipeBahans
        {
            get { return _tipebahans; }
            set { _tipebahans = value; }
        }

        private SolidColorBrush _tbbackground;

        public SolidColorBrush TBBackground
        {
            get { return _tbbackground; }
            set { _tbbackground = value; FirePropertyChanged("TBBackground"); }//NotifyPropertyChanged("TBBackground"); }
        }

        private bool _isreadonly;

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return _isreadonly; }
            set { _isreadonly = value; FirePropertyChanged("IsReadOnly"); }
            //NotifyPropertyChanged("IsReadOnly"); }
        }

        private ICommand _addnewbahancommand;
        public ICommand AddNewBahanCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_addnewbahancommand == null)
                {
                    _addnewbahancommand = new RelayCommand(AddNewBahanExecute, CanAddNewBahanExecute, false);
                }
                return _addnewbahancommand;
            }
        }

        private void AddNewBahanExecute(object parameter)
        {

        }

        private bool CanAddNewBahanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NewLebar)|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(NewPanjang)|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(HurufKodeBahan)|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(NoAwal) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(NoAkhir) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(NewSuratJalan))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        private ICommand _deletebahancommand;
        public ICommand DeleteBahanCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_deletebahancommand == null)
                {
                    _deletebahancommand = new RelayCommand(DeleteBahanExecute, CanDeleteBahanExecute, false);
                }
                return _deletebahancommand;
            }
        }

        private void DeleteBahanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            OkCancelButtonVis = "Visible"; //this is where the user interface failed to show the Ok and Cancel Button
            LabelContent = "Delete " + HurufKodeBahan + "-" + NoAwal + " to " + NoAkhir +" ?";//This is where the Label Content failed to show up

        }

        private bool CanDeleteBahanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HurufKodeBahan) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(NoAwal) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(NoAkhir))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        private ICommand _addnewtipebahancommand;
        public ICommand AddNewTipeBahanCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_addnewtipebahancommand == null)
                {
                    _addnewtipebahancommand = new RelayCommand(AddNewTipeBahanExecute, CanAddNewTipeBahanExecute, false);
                }
                return _addnewtipebahancommand;
            }
        }

        private void AddNewTipeBahanExecute(object parameter)
        {

        }

        private bool CanAddNewTipeBahanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NewNamaTipeBahan) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(NewGsm) )
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        private ICommand _okcommand;
        public ICommand OkCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_okcommand == null)
                {
                    _okcommand = new RelayCommand(OkExecute, CanOkExecute, false);
                }
                return _okcommand;
            }
        }

        private void OkExecute(object parameter)
        {
            SqlDbConnect sdc = new SqlDbConnect();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr;
            string tmpKodeBahan;
            int tmpNo, tmpCount;
            tmpNo = int.Parse(NoAwal);
            while (tmpNo <= int.Parse(NoAkhir))
            {
                tmpKodeBahan = HurufKodeBahan + "-" + tmpNo.ToString();
                sdc.SqlQuery("select TmpCount=count(*) from TBahan where Replace(Replace(KodeBahan,'-',''),' ','')= Replace(Replace('" + tmpKodeBahan + "','-',''),' ','')");
                ds = sdc.QueryEx("TBahan");
                dt = ds.Tables["TBahan"];
                dr = dt.Rows[0];
                tmpCount = (int)dr["TmpCount"];
                if (tmpCount > 0)
                {
                    sdc.SqlQuery("delete from TBahan where Replace(Replace(KodeBahan,'-',''),' ','')=Replace(Replace('" + tmpKodeBahan + "','-',''),' ','')");
                    sdc.NonQueryEx();
                }
                tmpNo++;
            }

            LabelContent = "Delete is done";
            sdc.SqlDbClose();
            OkCancelButtonVis = "Hidden";
        }

        private bool CanOkExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;

        }

        private ICommand _cancelcommand;
        public ICommand CancelCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_cancelcommand == null)
                {
                    _cancelcommand = new RelayCommand(CancelExecute, CanCancelExecute, false);
                }
                return _cancelcommand;
            }
        }

        private void CancelExecute(object parameter)
        {
            //hide ok cancel button
            OkCancelButtonVis = "Hidden";
            LabelContent = "";

        }

        private bool CanCancelExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ViewModels Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace XLMPIS.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModels 
    {
        public ViewModels()
        {

        }
        private static object inventoryViewModel = new NSViewModelExtensions.ResettableViewModel(new InventoryViewModel());

        public static object InventoryViewModel
        {
            get
            { 
                return ViewModels.inventoryViewModel;
            }

        }

        private static object bahanViewModel = new NSViewModelExtensions.ResettableViewModel(new BahanViewModel());

        public static object BahanViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return ViewModels.bahanViewModel;
            }

        }

        private static object spkdetailViewModel = new NSViewModelExtensions.ResettableViewModel(new SPKDetailViewModel());

        public static object SPKDetailViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return ViewModels.spkdetailViewModel;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is the ResettableViewModel Class

```
   using System;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Windows.Input;

   namespace NSViewModelExtensions
   {
       [TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(ResettableViewModelTypeDescriptionProvider))]
       sealed class ResettableViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
       {
           public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

           private void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
           {
               PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

               if (handler != null)
               {
                   handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
               }
           }

           private static string ErrorViewModelTypeHasToMatch = "The type of the new View Model has to match that of the old View Model.";

           private Func<object> creatorMethod;

           public ResettableViewModel(object innerViewModel, Func<object> creatorMethod = null)
           {
               this.InnerViewModel = innerViewModel;
               this.creatorMethod = creatorMethod;
           }

           public ResettableViewModel(Func<object> creatorMethod)
           {
               this.InnerViewModel = (this.creatorMethod = creatorMethod)();            
           }

           public ResettableViewModel(Type innerViewModelType)
           {
               this.InnerViewModel = Activator.CreateInstance(innerViewModelType);
           }

           internal object InnerViewModel { get; private set; }

           private ICommand resetCommand;

           public ICommand ResetCommand
           {
               get
               {
                   return resetCommand ?? (resetCommand = new InternalDelegateCommand(() =>
                       {
                              if (creatorMethod == null)
                               {
                                   this.InnerViewModel = Activator.CreateInstance(this.InnerViewModel.GetType());
                               }
                              else
                           {
                                    var newViewModel = creatorMethod();

                             if (this.InnerViewModel.GetType() != newViewModel.GetType())
                                     {
                                         throw new InvalidOperationException(ResettableViewModel.ErrorViewModelTypeHasToMatch);
                                     }

                             this.InnerViewModel = newViewModel;
                                }

                         FirePropertyChanged(String.Empty);
                        }));
               }
           }

           class InternalDelegateCommand : ICommand
           {
               private readonly Action executeMethod;

               public InternalDelegateCommand(Action executeMethod)
               {
                   this.executeMethod = executeMethod;
               }

               public void Execute(object parameter)
               {
                   if (this.executeMethod != null)
                 {
                        this.executeMethod();
                    }
               }

               public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
               {
                   return true;
               }

              public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
          }
      }
  }
```

There also 4 other classes that Nish used, which are available from the link above :

1. ResettableViewModelCustomField.cs
2. ResettableViewModelCustomFieldPropertyDescriptor.cs
3. ResettableViewModelCustomTypeDescriptor.cs
4. ResettableViewModelTypeDescriptionProvider.cs

Comment: The BahanViewModel and the properties with your issue has nothing to do with that ResetableViewModel. Why do you mention it at all? It only put some strange noise into the question as well as 90% of your code here. Please read [What is a MCVE?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: BahanViewModel contains the DeleteBahanExecute command which fails to update the Label Content and Ok & Cancel button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up abandoning the ResettableViewModel and used Initialize method in my constructor. I just called this Initialize method whenever I need to reset the view model.